# How to concatenate strings and variables so that quotes in the variables are escaped?

Tags: purescript

I am using `readJSON` which, in case of error, yields `Left err`. Sometimes this error (a string) contains quotation marks, e. g. `ReferenceError: "JSON" is not defined.` I need to return this error wrapped in a JSON string, sort of like

```
Left err -> "{ \"error\" : \"The error is: " ++ (show err) ++ "\" }"
```

(the `show` is needed because we are in a fail monad.)

But when `err` has quotation marks like the example above, this rips the JSON apart. How to get this working?

(In PSCI, `show` seems to do a good job of escaping things, e. g. `show "\"foo\""` yields a fireworks of `\`. But inside a function as above, not?)

Comment: You should not build your JSON with string concatenation. Use `JSON.stringify`, which will handle the encoding. *edit:* I assume pursescript has that as well, or something similar.

Comment: Thanks. You wouldn’t happen to know how to do that in PureScript, would you? (I am not a JS expert.) I can build a JSON *object*, but the calling function (Java / Rhino) expects a string back.

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off using [`purescript-argonaut`](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-argonaut) rather than `purescript-foreign` for your use case here. If you `show` an argonaut JSON value it will use `JSON.stringify` to produce the value.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that there are alternatives. So far my code relies on `purescript-foreign`. I might look into what it means to change that or to use a mix, meaning using `purescript-argonaut` just for that one case.

Comment: See also my comment to the answer by @Christoph Hegemann: I think this is a generic issue not necessarily related to JSON. I think it has to do with `show` in PureScript or some other way of taking care of quotes when concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

The "lightweight" way would be to call [Global.Unsafe.unsafeStringify](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-globals/0.2.2/docs/Global.Unsafe#v:unsafeStringify) which is just an FFI call to JSON.stringify. If this happens more often you're better of using Argonaut as @gb said though.

Comment: I’m wondering: Isn’t my question a general one, one of concatenating two strings, one of which having quotes that need to be escaped? (I’m not sure if this is a JSON issue at all.)

Comment: A string is a completely valid piece of JSON on its own. I think your question is more about serializing strings, which in js world is done using JSON.stringify.